# Is there a way to Embed Facebook Videos?

Tags: files, nodes

D7.37:

I am Trying to embed Facebook Videos and cannot find a way to do it.

Points:

1. Have already installed: Media-Module, Oembed, Media-YouTube, but cannot get Oembed to actually embed anything.
2. The Media-YouTube works; I can embed YouTube Videos.
3. I can embed SoundCloud Audio.
4. I can embed Flickr Images.
5. I cannot get anything Facebook related to embed.
6. Is this even possible in D7?
7. I tried downloading the Video-Lightbox software, but it would not take URL's from Facebook.

When I try to “cut & paste” the Facebook URL into the Video-Light-Box software, the URL seems to be loading then just terminates producing nothing.  If I do the same thing with a YouTube-Video an actual file is embedded.

When I try to embed the Facebook URL via the Media-Module-Browser, I get an error “SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'oembed://https%3A//www.facebook.com/AnimalsAustralia/videos/1015' for key 'uri'”; however the file brokenly loads and then is only available as a Link to Facebook NOT an Embed.

When I try to embed the Facebook URL via the WYSIWYG-Editor-AddMedia Button, either as a new Facebook URL or an entry from the Media-Library, a small Icon appears which is also only a Link and not an Embed.

When I try to embed the Facebook URL via the WYSIWYG-Editor-AddMedia Button, but wrapped in [embed] {Facebook URL} [/embed] tags, I receive an “Unable to handle the provided embed string or URL” error message.

BTW I have scoured the settings to be sure that "Rendered-File" is selected in the Media-Display settings of this Content-Type.  I have a Content-Type set up specifically for handing Media and configured to allow Remote Media Types of Video.

What might I be missing?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a Media-module solution, or are you just trying to get the videos embedded? While YouTube uses an iframe, Facebook uses a script tag, which your text format may be stripping out.

Comment: No, I would prefer a Media-Module solution or an OEmbed solution, but at this stage anything is an option.  I can see that probably Facebook gains nothing by sending its cherished content to other sites as embeds, so Facebook probably is not in any hurry to provide a solution.

Comment: BTW, I have tried just a "cut & paste" approach to the Facebook Video in an Article-Content-Type, but that fails as well.  AND I used the FULL-HTML-Option.

Comment: Can you specify whether the player loads and doesn't play, or whether the the player doesn't load at all? Facebook video embeds seem to work fine for me. http://demo.latticegroup.com/node/7

Comment: Because there is no way to format these responses, I have added the response into the original Question above.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to embed facebook, youtube and vimeo videos in a view using just the following:

1. Drupal version:  7.54
2. Media Module version:  7.x-2.0-rc5
3. Media: oEmbed Module version:  7.x-2.7
4. Entity view modes module: 7.x-1.0-rc1 // optional

Facebook URL:  https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10153231379946729

Try the above URL format.  If the video still won't embed, then it's probably the configuration.

---

My media field in the content type is setup as follows:

1. Field Type:  File
2. Widget:  Media Browser
3. Enabled browser plugins:  Upload and Web
4. Allowed file types: Image and Video
5. Allowed URI schemes: oEmbed resources and Public files
6. Allowed file extensions for uploaded files:  png, gif, jpg, jpeg

Note this field supports both images and videos.

---

Then you need to setup your file display for videos here:

/admin/structure/file-types/manage/video/file-display

I used the Entity view modes module to create a a new view mode for this field.  Then I selected the oEmbed formatter for my view mode.

---

Then in the view, select the Rendered file formatter and the view mode you created.

---

Then when creating the node, try the above url.